# Get first item in list using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How do I get the first item from a list into a variable?

I'm trying to get the first window of an application's windows.

I tried

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with theProcess in processes
        if not background only of theProcess then
            if processName is "Xcode" then
                set theWindow to first window of windows
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

but it throws this error:

> Can't get window of every window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have an explicit need for going about it in the manner shown in your question, I'd keep it much more simple and use:

```
tell application "System Events" to set isRunning to exists (processes where name is "Xcode")
if isRunning then set theWindow to (first window of application "Xcode")
```

Otherwise, modifying your existing *code block* in the following manner will get that same result as the two lines of *code* above:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with theProcess in processes
        if not background only of theProcess then
            if name of theProcess is "Xcode" then
                tell application "Xcode"
                    set theWindow to first window of application "Xcode"
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you want to use the first two line of *code* in my answer in a more tokenized manned, as an example, use:

```
set appName to "Xcode"
tell application "System Events" to set isRunning to exists (processes where name is appName)
if isRunning then set theWindow to (first window of application appName)
```

Then all you need to do is set `appName` to the target app in the first line of *code* and the two lines of *code* following it stand as is and do not need to be edited for use with other app names.

Comment: What does the `isRunning` keyword?

Comment: I don't want the name of the window.

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei, `isRunning` is  not a _keyword_, it's a _variable_, which gets set to either `true` or `false` depending on if the process exists. If you don't want the name of the window, what do you want?

Comment: The window object, if there is such thing. I somehow want to retrieve some checkboxes in that window.

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei, I've edited it to give the `window` not the `name`.

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei, I just wanted to add that `if isRunning then` is equivalent to `if isRunning is equal to true then`, so, depending on the actual _value_ of `isRunning`, it equates to either `if true is equal to true then` or `if false is equal to true then` ... So the remaining _code_ on that line only executes if the _value_ of `isRuning` is `true`.

Comment: Yes, I understood that after your previous comment, thank you!

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei, I figured you did, but wanted to make sure, and also have it available for others that might read this thread and don't have a full understanding of how the _code_ works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `first window of windows` try `item 1 of windows`

As pointed out by others, your code may have additional issues to work through but using the syntax suggested in this answer can be used to overcome the issue of retrieving the first object in a list of objects.